# why use q15 over standard int16 for embedded

Tags: c, embedded, signal-processing

I'm looking at the ARM CMSIS DSP Library and wondering if there is an advantage speed wise to operating in the q15 1to-1 range vs staying in the standard int16 range 32kto-32k.

Comment: Q15 is fixed point format for representing real numbers. `int16_t` is an integer format. So you are kind of comparing apples to oranges...

Comment: @EugeneSh.: `int16_t` is a fixed-point format for representing real numbers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK, OK, I get the point...

Comment: @EricPostpischil by "real numbers" Eugene is referring to the Reals. `int16_t` cannot represent the Reals (except for integers).

Comment: @rlbond, Eugene and Eric both understand that very well.  The point is that the two data formats differ only in interpretation of the same data representations -- in their units, as it were.  Yes, Q15 can represent some non-integer rational numbers, but it can represent only three integers, and no numbers at all with absolute value greater than 1.  It does not have a particularly better (or worse) claim on being a "real" number format than `int16_t` does.

Comment: @rlbond: In addition to John Bollinger’s information, my point is that people mistakenly think of numeric formats as different in ways they are not. In this case, the properties of Q15 (also known as Q0.15) and `int16_t`(also known as Q15.0) are identical except for scale. They both represent a limited subset of real numbers. The OP is not, as was said, comparing apples to oranges. They are really asking whether there is some speed advantage in using Q15 (and scaling may be done in hardware, if the processor has the necessary features) versus using `int16_t` (and doing the scaling themselves).

Comment: @rlbond: So it is not a question about the mathematical properties of the formats; whether they are reals or integers is of no relevance in this case.

Comment: Yes, obviously all 16-bit fixed point representations are congruent, I just found the initial comment unhelpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 * 1 = 1.

32k * 32k > 32k.

The result of Q15 multiplication is guaranteed to fit inside of a Q15.  This makes it very convenient in DSP where arrays of numbers must be quickly multiplied and summed.

Answer (score 2):

You ask,

> I'm looking at the ARM CMSIS DSP Library and wondering if there is an
>   advantage speed wise to operating in the q15 1to-1 range vs staying in
>   the standard int16 range 32kto-32k.

Since CMSIS DSP seems not to offer function variants that differ only in whether they are operating on `Q15` data or `int16_t` data, I take you to be inquiring about why the API was designed as it was, and in particular about whether processing speed was a factor.

Certainly processing speed was a factor in offering variants that operate on fixed-point data in addition to those that operate on floating-point data, but there is no reason to think that computations with `Q15` data would be faster than computations with *`int16_t`* data.  I'm inclined to think that the advantage of `Q15` is that the -1 ... 1 perceived range simplifies scaling logic.  Additionally, -1 ... 1 or the positive half of that is the natural range for a number of significant functions, such as the sine, the cosine, and Gaussians.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the lame intro, but your answer depends on the data.  If you are using normalized data (spanning from [-1.0,1.0]), by all means, stick with the q15 library.  Under the hood, both a q15xq15 and int16xint16 will perform a 16 bit by 16 multiply resulting in a 32 bit value. 
If you are working with scaled integers (the q15) the result would be in the upper 16 bits of the 32-bit result.  If you are working integers and the resultant container was only 16 bits, you have to worry about detecting overflows.
If you do a side by side test, I expect the library performance would be similar, the main concern is detection of overflows.
If this is for a vector or signal processing operation and you cannot afford to use 32-bit values, go with the fixed point (the q15).  I have worked on projects where people tried implementing Q15s using 16 bit integers and they kept on introducing unintended math errors.

Comment: I can't understand what is the problem in upper 16bit and what is scaled integer meaning?

Comment: Sorry Mohammadsdtmnd..   I didn't quite understand the question, however here is an article on half precision floats.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format